# Implementing RGB in QML using Qt3D

Tags: c++, qt, qml, mesh, realsense

Hey The meshviewer shows a default color which I know how to change as you can see below.
But how can i change that color into the rgb data I get from my 3D camera using a Intel RealSense Camera? Does anyone have experience with this. I was looking in to Qt3D.Render but I can't figure it out.

```
PhongMaterial {
    id: reconstructedMeshMaterial
    ambient: "#F6C6AF"
}
```

[Output Meshviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av8CD.png)

Comment: Maybe I don't get your question, but don't you need texture mapping in order to solve that? Otherwise setting color is per 3d object. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick3d-texture.html

Comment: does `ambient: Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 1)` work?

Comment: @seleciii44 it does work isn't it the same with the Hex number, but basically in rgb. I try to use the RGB data the camera makes

Comment: @iam_peter isn't texture mapping putting a picture on the mesh. Is that same as giving each vector the rgb values?

Comment: Setting the color per vertex is a matter of setting up the VBO properly. The material is per 3d object, but not per vertex. Have a look at that SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324366/how-to-color-each-triangle-differently-using-vbo

Comment: @JKac by rgb data you mean a whole image? I thought you you were try to set only one pixel from that data.

Comment: @seleciii44 Yeah thet intel realsense camera, is a 3d camera which gives 2 streams depth stream and a rgb stream. With that information i can make a 3D mesh. But the only problem I dont know how to impelement that RGB stream in Qt/QML which should be possible

Answer (score 1):

I've created an [example project](https://github.com/iam-peter/customgeometry) for you based on the [Qt Quick 3D - Custom Geometry Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick3d-customgeometry-example.html). It shows how to set a color per vertex using a vertex buffer. It uses `QQuick3DGeometry` to create a custom geometry that can be used in QML. The important part is to understand how to create the vertex buffer consisting of a position (x, y, z) and color (r, g, b, a). After setting the data the vertex buffer needs to be configured using the `addAttribute()` function. The documentation can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquick3dgeometry.html#addAttribute).

```
void ExampleTriangleGeometry::updateData()
{
    clear();

    // PositionSemantic: The attribute is a position. 3 components: x, y, and z
    // ColorSemantic: The attribute is a vertex color vector. 4 components: r, g, b, and a
    int stride = 7 * sizeof(float);

    // 3 vertices in total for the triangle
    QByteArray vertexData(3 * stride, Qt::Initialization::Uninitialized);
    float *p = reinterpret_cast<float *>(vertexData.data());

    // a triangle, front face = counter-clockwise
    *p++ = -1.0f; // x
    *p++ = -1.0f; // y
    *p++ = 0.0f;  // z

    *p++ = 1.0f; // r
    *p++ = 0.0f; // g
    *p++ = 0.0f; // b
    *p++ = 1.0f; // a

    *p++ = 1.0f;
    *p++ = -1.0f;
    *p++ = 0.0f;

    *p++ = 0.0f;
    *p++ = 1.0f;
    *p++ = 0.0f;
    *p++ = 1.0f;

    *p++ = 0.0f;
    *p++ = 1.0f;
    *p++ = 0.0f;

    *p++ = 0.0f;
    *p++ = 0.0f;
    *p++ = 1.0f;
    *p++ = 1.0f;

    setVertexData(vertexData);
    setStride(stride);
    setBounds(QVector3D(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), QVector3D(+1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f));

    setPrimitiveType(QQuick3DGeometry::PrimitiveType::Triangles);

    addAttribute(QQuick3DGeometry::Attribute::PositionSemantic,
                 0,
                 QQuick3DGeometry::Attribute::F32Type);

    addAttribute(QQuick3DGeometry::Attribute::ColorSemantic,
                 3 * sizeof(float),
                 QQuick3DGeometry::Attribute::F32Type);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, with this program you have written that you can decide what color you want. But i don't want to do that I would like  to use the RGB Data I get from my Intel RealSense D415 camera, is that possible? I've done quite alot of research but I can't figure it out yet

Comment: I don't know how the data looks like. I don't own such a camera. I suspect that it outputs some kind of height maps and color textures. Can you provide sample data?

Comment: it creates a ply file which we import in the qml gui. Only for some reason it doesn't show the color. Here's a link how  a ply file look like: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/

Comment: You can use the cube rgb example below as reference. I want to show that on a GUI with the color if that's possible.

Comment: You can export a point cloud with colors from the Intel RealSense Viewer https://www.andreasjakl.com/capturing-3d-point-cloud-intel-realsense-converting-mesh-meshlab/

Comment: Yes I know that but QML/Qt for some reason cant show the RGB data it shows one plain color.

Comment: This is why I want to get my hands on a sample ply to test it myself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786536/qml-load-and-display-ply-mesh-with-color-attributes

Comment: I came across that to thats 4 years ago so i thought maybe theres implementation still can't figure it out yet. Also if you want a sample ply you can use this link: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/ 
Down below under "Another Example" can you see a ply file which is a 3d cube with color, when you copy that file change the extension to ply(also remove the comments to the right).  When you open it in MeshLab you can see the cube with color for test purposes

Comment: did it work out with the sample ply

Comment: The assimp integrated into QtQuick isn't capable of loading ply with vertex colors. The only option I see is to use my demo and write a custom loader based on libassimp. libassimp can load ply, but the conversion to a VBO and setting up the attribute information needs to be done extra. I didn't have time yet to write a demo application, but this would be also limited in its capabilities. You could write it yourself depending on what you actually want to support in terms of ply featuers.